# Flutter Android: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.1

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

Gradle cannot find a valid gradle release, which end up outputting that error:

```
2023-05-25T16:14:16.244+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Configure build' completed
 
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
 * What went wrong:
 A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
    > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.1.
      Searched in the following locations:
        - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.1/gradle-7.5.1.pom
        - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.1/gradle-7.5.1.pom
        - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.1/gradle-7.5.1.pom
      Required by:
          project :
```

```
# android/build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research, apparently these repos support a subset of gradle not all versions, so it was the case that the version didn't actually exist.

Solution is to open the google maven repo web version, search for gradle and see supported versions and choose the closest one to your liking:

https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.android.tools.build:gradle

In my case, choosing: 7.5.x was not there at all, so I had to resort to manual download and inclusion

**Here is how:**

1. download the zip release file:
   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip

```
unzip gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
mkdir -p ./android/ext
```

2. move the gradle 7.5 directory there
3. edit ./android/app/build.gradle
   under dependencies include the directory in question

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'ext/gradle-7.5', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

4. go to ./android and run

```
./gradlew clean
```

should be good to go

Hope that helps someone, somewhere :)